# Query shopp categories and CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-shopp

I have a slider setup that is querying shopp categories that have products here: http://halliescomet.com/

Here's my code:

```
<div class="flexslider-holder">
<div class="flexslider-container">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php if( shopp('catalog','has-categories')) : ?>
             <?php while(shopp('catalog','categories')): ?>
             <?php
            // Skip sub-categories
            if (shopp('category','parent','return=1') > 0) continue;  ?>
             <li>
                        <a href='<?php shopp('category','url'); ?>'> 
                        <?php shopp('category','coverimage','width=545&height=260&fit=crop'); ?><br style="clear: both;" />
                        </a>
                        <div class='flex-caption'>
                            <h2><?php shopp('category','name'); ?></h2>
                            <?php shopp('category','description'); ?>

                            <a class="learnmore" href="<?php shopp('category','url'); ?>">View All</a>
                        </div>


            </li>




        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_reset_query();?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd What I would like to do is combine that with a custom post type labeled "slides" so I am able to add non shopp content to the slider. Anyone know if this is do-able? Since the shopp  while is different I am not sure how to go about this.

Any help is again appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using a custom query. Or you just create an array and load the shopp items to it and then the items of your custom post type.

Comment: So, would you set up something like this? 
    query_posts( array(  'post_type' => array( 'slides', '(shopp('catalog','categories'))' ) ) );

if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

Comment: exactly. but don't forget to reset the query after this.

Comment: If I don't would it kill my page?  I tried it without resetting and it did :)

Comment: better do so there will be no error with any plugins or if you want to add a blog or so ;)

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding this fully, Would I need to add an if else statement in the list items below as well?

Comment: bettter use new WP_Query() instead of query posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Ok, that didn't help.  I think I will need to setup an if else section that will display the content from either the shopp category or cpt.